# Hashed password and mailing through Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a contact form that when clicking the submit button, an email will be send to the person contacting me and myself for follow-up. When I pass my real password (hardcoded) to my Mailer function, the mails get sent.
I use Gmail to send the mails and store the password hashed in my database. The hashing works as intended. I can retrieve the password as well.

But with a hashed password, I get an error (which is normal because wrong credentials - authentication failed). Somehow I need to pass the hashed password unhashed to my Gmail.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Why do you save the password, you use for sending with gmail, in the database?

Comment: If it's hashed, then you can't really use it to login into GMAIL.

Comment: Passwords, or API keys, used by an application should not be stored inside the database, instead look at [safely storing your secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows)

Comment: A main feature of hashes is that you can't reverse them. There are many options, all of which introduce some risk. I would suggest maybe Azure KeyVault as the location for your password. It is cheap and relatively easy to integrate.

Comment: It was indeed a bad idea to store that password in the database. I'm looking into secrets and Azure KeyVault now thanks to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a bad idea to store that password in the database. I'm moving forward with secrets and looking into Azure KeyVault.